# This program will not register clicks in certain graphic objects but will in others. What am I missing here?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, graphics

I am trying to make a program that will increase the speed of the moving blue circle by 50% if the yellow square is clicked, and decrease it by 50% if the purple square is clicked. The purple square works fine but the yellow square will not register clicks at all. Interestingly, if the black square is used in place of the yellow square, it will function as necessary. Additionally, the blue circle will register clicks within it but will not close the window as intended. I am a novice in python and am beyond confused here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

As stated previously, functionality works as intended when the black square is used to carry out the functionality of the yellow square. I have used print statements to test if clicks are being registered in different shapes. Clicks register in the blue circle, black square and purple square, but not in the yellow square.

```
from graphics import*
from time import sleep
def main():
    win,c=make()
    yellow=Rectangle(Point(495,200),Point(395,300))
    yellow.setFill("yellow")
    yellow.draw(win)
    purple=Rectangle(Point(5,200),Point(105,300))
    purple.setFill("purple")
    purple.draw(win)
    black=Rectangle(Point(200,5),Point(300,105))
    black.setFill("black")
    black.draw(win)
    z=0.2
    dx,dy=3,-6
    while True:
        c.move(dx,dy)
        sleep(z)
        center=c.getCenter()
        dx,dy=bounce(dx,dy,center)
        point=win.checkMouse()
        if point != None:
            if isClicked(point,yellow):
                z=z-0.05
            elif isClicked(point,purple):
                z=z+0.05
            elif isClicked(point,c):
                win.close

def bounce(dx,dy,center):
    if center.getX()<25 or center.getX()>475:
        dx *= -1
    if center.getY()<25 or center.getY()>475:
        dy *= -1
    if (center.getX() > 370 and center.getX() < 470) and (center.getY() >175 and center.getY() < 325):
        dx *= -1
        dy *= -1
    return dx,dy


def isClicked(click, shape):
    # verify that click is a Point object otherwise return False
    if not click:
        return False
    # get the X,Y coordinates of the mouse click
    x,y = click.getX(), click.getY()   
    # check if shape is a Circle
    if type(shape).__name__ == 'Circle':
        center = shape.getCenter()
        cx, cy = center.getX(), center.getY()
        # if click is within the Circle return True
        if ((x-cx)**2 + (y-cy)**2)**.5 <= 25:
            return True
    # shape must be a Rectangle
    else:
        x1, y1 = shape.getP1().getX(), shape.getP1().getY()
        x2, y2 = shape.getP2().getX(), shape.getP2().getY()
        # if click is within the Rectangle
        if (x1 < x < x2) and (y1 < y < y2):
            return True
    # click was not inside the shape
    return False

def make():
    win = GraphWin('Tester',500,500)
    win.setBackground('grey')

    c = Circle(Point(250,250),25)
    c.setFill('blue')
    c.draw(win)

    return win, c

main()
```

As stated previously, the intended function would be that a click in the purple rectangle would slow the circle by 50% and a click in the yellow rectangle should increase speed by 50%. Currently a click in the circle does nothing, as does a click in the yellow square. Additionally, a click in the blue circle should close the circle. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: instead of `type(shape).__name__ == 'Circle'` you can use `isinstance(shape, Circle)`

Comment: you forgot `()` in `win.close()`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `()` in `win.close()` and it never run this function. You could also add `break` to exit loop because `win.close()` only close window but it doesn't end loop which still try to `win.checkMouse()` but `win` doesn't exists any more and it gives error.

---

Problem with yellow rectangle is because first X is bigger then second X (495 > 395) in

```
yellow = Rectangle(Point(495, 200), Point(395, 300))
```

and Rectangle doesn't sort these values so finally this is not true

```
if (x1 < x < x2) and (y1 < y < y2)
```

If you change it to

```
yellow = Rectangle(Point(395,200),Point(495,300))
```

then it works correctly.

---

BTW:

Instead of `type(shape).__name__ == 'Circle'` you can use `isinstance(shape, Circle)`

You could add some spaces and empty lines to make it more readable.

Using `import *` is not prefered - but this part I didn't change.

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Instead of `if point != None:` you should rather use `if point is not None:` or shorter `if point:`

---

```
from graphics import *
from time import sleep

def main():
    win, c = make()

    yellow = Rectangle(Point(395, 200), Point(495, 300))
    yellow.setFill("yellow")
    yellow.draw(win)

    purple = Rectangle(Point(5, 200), Point(105, 300))
    purple.setFill("purple")
    purple.draw(win)

    black = Rectangle(Point(200, 5), Point(300, 105))
    black.setFill("black")
    black.draw(win)

    z = 0.2
    dx, dy = 3, -6

    while True:
        c.move(dx, dy)
        sleep(z)

        center = c.getCenter()
        dx, dy = bounce(dx, dy, center)

        point = win.checkMouse()
        #if point is not None:
        if point:
            if isClicked(point, yellow):
                z = z - 0.05
            elif isClicked(point, purple):
                z = z + 0.05
            elif isClicked(point, c):
                win.close()
                break

def bounce(dx, dy, center):
    if center.getX() < 25 or center.getX() > 475:
        dx *= -1
    if center.getY() < 25 or center.getY() > 475:
        dy *= -1
    if (center.getX() > 370 and center.getX() < 470) and (center.getY() > 175 and center.getY() < 325):
        dx *= -1
        dy *= -1
    return dx, dy


def isClicked(click, shape):
    # verify that click is a Point object otherwise return False
    if not click:
        return False

    # get the X,Y coordinates of the mouse click
    x, y = click.getX(), click.getY()

    # check if shape is a Circle
    if isinstance(shape, Circle):
        center = shape.getCenter()
        cx, cy = center.getX(), center.getY()
        # if click is within the Circle return True
        if ((x-cx)**2 + (y-cy)**2)**.5 <= 25:
            return True

    # shape must be a Rectangle
    else:
        x1, y1 = shape.getP1().getX(), shape.getP1().getY()
        x2, y2 = shape.getP2().getX(), shape.getP2().getY()
        # if click is within the Rectangle
        if (x1 < x < x2) and (y1 < y < y2):
            return True

    # click was not inside the shape
    return False

def make():
    win = GraphWin('Tester', 500, 500)
    win.setBackground('grey')

    c = Circle(Point(250, 250), 25)
    c.setFill('blue')
    c.draw(win)

    return win, c

main()
```